# How can I call a function when jQuery $.post is complete?

Tags: jquery, post

The data is posting fine to the db, but neither the alert or page refresh below are called afterwards. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post(document.URL + '/image', {'image_strength' : _imageStrength}) 
    .done(function(){
        alert('anything');
        location.reload(); 
    });


$.post(document.URL + '/image', {'image_strength' : _imageStrength}, 
    function(){
        alert('asdfasdf');
        location.reload(); 
    });
```

Comment: Have you verified that the AJAX call is successful? Try adding an error handler and see if it's called.

Comment: The data shows up in the mongo db.

Comment: Keep in mind just because your data shows in up in the DB, it doesn't mean that there's no component of your application that doesn't throw any error. Error could still occur after the data is written, and might result in a failed AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what that means. I tried `window.onerror = function() {
     alert("Error caught");
 };` right after the post, but no alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [`deferred.done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) function will only fire its callback if the deferred object (in this case the result of `$.post()`) resolves.  Try adding some `.fail()` and `.always()` callbacks and you should see at least *some* result.  Try this to see what's going on with your `$.post()`:

```
$.post(document.URL + '/image', {'image_strength' : _imageStrength}) 
    .done(function(){
        alert('anything');
        location.reload(); 
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('failed');
    })
    .always(function(){
        alert('finished');
    });
```

Comment: Believe it or not, I see nothing, and yet it still successfully posted. This `setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 250);` solved my problem, but still I'm curious as to why what u and posted didn't alert anything.

Comment: Actually I take that back.  It called failed and finished when I tried to navigate away from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the response of the webservice. For example in chrome open firebug (right click -> inspect element) than select network tab. Is really useful to debug what the problem is and you will see much more information about your webservice than into an alert() dialog.